# Решить пример записав его условие не используя массивы

Tags: c#

В начале пытался записать через 
    for( int i = 1; i==256; i*2){}
Но что-то пошло не так и я не смог понять,как делить до определенного делителя, не используя массивы[image: сам пример, который нужно записать с помощью программы]

Comment: добирайтесь наоборот, снизу вверх, от 256 до 0 - и считайте промежуточный результат на каждом шаге

Comment: @PashaPash А есть ли в этом смысл? Я прост сюда пишу, когда уже заканчиваются идеи по задаче. Просто в любом случае, чтоб пользоваться этим циклом и записать этот пример мне нужно запомнить то, что у меня получилось в 1 заход цикла

Comment: @FlyFox смысл есть - массив в этом случае не нужен будет.

Comment: а как тут вообще массивы можно использовать?

Comment: @Grundy если подумать, этот вопрос неожиданно оказывается сложным. По идее, можно попытаться промежуточные результаты хранить в массиве, но толку от этого никакого. Идти сверху вниз массив тоже не позволит...

Answer (score 5):

При расчете "снизу вверх" получается так:

```
var x = 5.0;
var xSquare = x * x;
var result = xSquare;
for (var i = 256; i >= 2; i /= 2)
    result = xSquare + i / result;
result = x / result;
```

Comment: Мне кажется. что вот эта строчка `result = x / (xSquare + result);` должна быть такой `result = x / result;`

Comment: @tym32167 да, действительно, спасибо. То-то у меня с WolframAlpha ответ не сходился...

Answer (score 3):

Linq-вариант для полноты картины:

```
double x = 5;
double r = x * Enumerable.Range(0, 9).Aggregate(0.0, (t, i) => (1 << (8 - i)) / (x * x + t));
Console.WriteLine(r); // 0.19936603598533
```

Answer (score 2):

Набросал кода, вроде выполняет вашу задачу.

```
int i = 256;
double x = 5;
double pow = Math.Pow(x, 2);
double result = pow;
while (i / 2 != 0)
{
    result = pow + (i / result);
    i /= 2;
}

result = x / (pow + result);
```

Comment: `Math.Pow(x, 2)` имеет смысл сделать один раз, а в дальнейшем использовать вычисленное значение.

Comment: Что-то у меня такое подозрение, что код неправильный. Должно быть `result = Math.Pow(x, 2)+ i / result;`

Comment: @Regent да, вы правы, поменял ответ

Comment: вот тут `result = x / (pow + result);` pow по моему не нужна

Answer (score 2):

Рекурсивный вариант

```
double Calc(double x, int i = 1)
{
    if (i == 256) return x*x+i/(x*x);       
    if (i == 1) return x / Calc(x, 2);
    return x*x + i / Calc(x, i*2);
}

Console.WriteLine(Calc(5));
```

Который вернет ещё и верный ответ 0.19936603598533